# SetContentAsync does not complete before PdfDataAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi, puppeteer-sharp

Consider the following code:

```
var content = "my-quite-long-html-string";
var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions { Headless = true  });
var page = await browser.NewPageAsync();

await page.SetContentAsync(content);
var pdfData = await page.PdfDataAsync(new PdfOptions { }); //*

await page.CloseAsync();

return Ok(pdfData);
```

- `pdfData` is sometimes set to the full valid `byte[]` but more than sometimes is just a partial result (i.e. 1088 bytes of actual 17899 bytes).

The whole snippet never throws any `Exceptions` nor does it ever interrupt from running to completion in any other way.

If I set a breakpoint at `await page.SetContentAsync(content);` and just wait a second before allowing execution to continue, the `pdfData` is always populated with full and correct data.

Also, when `SlowMo=50` in `LaunchOptions` (see below), the chances of `pdfData` being accurately set is increasing. Naturally this is just a hint of where the problem resides and not a solution to the problem.

```
var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions { Headless = true, SlowMo = 50 });
```

It appears to me that `SetContentAsync` takes some time to complete and that somehow the `await` finishes before the method has completely finished. Am I missing something, doing something wrong or is this a bug in `Puppeteer Sharp`?

Answer (score 1):

Add WaitForNavigationAsync() after your SetContentAsync() call to wait for the page content to load. By default it waits for the onLoad event, but you can use parameters to change it to wait for a different event.

```
await page.WaitForNavigationAsync();
```